# Do I need 'OK to board' and transit visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, ok-to-board

I will be travelling through spice jet from Ahmedabad to Muscat. I have a layover of 4h 15m in Muscat and then have a Pakistan International Airlines (PIA) flight from Muscat to karachi. I won't have any check-in luggage with me and have valid pakistani visa.

Do I need  'OK to Board' and/or transit visa?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: I am an indian national

Comment: What is "OK to Board" in this case? Please clarify this before we reopen. Thank you.